# AWS Lambda Node.js HTTP GET Request never executed

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have the following intent. When intent is entered I want to perform a GET request to an external API. The intent is entered, however my http.get requested is not. If you look below I added a log statement within the request and it is never executed. Any ideas what the problem may be?

```
'BlogEntrySlugIntent': function () {
  var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

  http.get( url, function( response ) {
    console.log('In get request');
    response.on( 'data', function( data ) {
      var text = 'Data returned is: ' + data;
      this.emit(':tell', 'hellloooo');
    });
  });
},
```

Comment: you loose context...

Comment: @Jonas w, not sure what you mean..

Comment: *this.emit()* => i believe *this* is global ...

Comment: Shouldn't my log statement still be executed? I don't think the request is even running.

Comment: It sounds like the HTTP request is actually timing out. Did you place the Lambda function in a VPC without a NAT gateway?

Comment: @Mark B, I'm not very familiar with VPC/NAT Gateways. I just checked and I have VPC set to No VPC.